# Referencing part of an array and appending information to that index

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to add one array to the end of a specific index of another array?

I want to search each index for a specific value (in this case "apple").
Then I want to add a line of data after an index that has "apple" as its first value.

First array:

```
Array
(
[0] => apple,1,2,3
[1] => orange,a,b,c
)
```

Second array:

```
Array 
(
[0] => apple,a,b,c
)
```

Final product:

```
Array
(
[0] => apple,1,2,3, apple,a,b,c
[1] => orange,a,b,c
)
```

Notice that I am ignoring the "orange" index because it did not match "apple".

I have tried "pushing" or "merging" the arrays but that does not seem to work.

Part of the problem is that I:

1. Do not know how to search an array for "Apple" if that word is part of a larger set of information within the array (e.g., apple, 1,2,3)
2. I do not know how to reference only part of an index (e.g., find part of the array that has "apple", and then add some information to that specific index).

Is this even possible to do? Excited to learn more about this!

Comment: sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Do you really need that specific structure `apple,1,2,3,` as a value? Wouldn't this be better as a sub-array of `apple`? Then your problem is easy...

Comment: Are the values (i.e. apple,1,2,3) strings or what?

Comment: It may be an XY problem. I do need to preserve order. If it is not possible with full arrays I would be curious to know how to do it with subarrays / converting the array to string.